# JSF CompositeComponent: Implement selection

Tags: java, jsf-2, composite-component

Hello I want to implement a CC similar which implements a *selection* attribute. This is similar to to Primefaces [instant row selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf) `<p:dataTable selection="#{bean.user}" .../>`.

This are the relevant definitions in the composite:

```
<composite:interface componentType="my.CcSelection">
  <composite:attribute name="actionListener" required="true"
          method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
  <composite:attribute name="selection"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  ...
  <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{cc.attrs.data}">
    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.actionListener(item)}"/>
  </ui:repeat>
  ...
</composite:implementation>
```

The `actionListener`-method in the backing bean is the following:

```
public void actionListener(MyObject object)
{
  logger.info("ActionListener "+object); //Always the correct object
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

  Iterator<String> it = this.getAttributes().keySet().iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()) {   //Only for debugging ...
    logger.debug(it.next());
  }

  // I want the set the value here
  ValueExpression veSelection = (ValueExpression)getAttributes().get("selection");
  veSelection.setValue(context.getELContext(), object);

  // And then call a method in a `@ManagedBean` (this works fine)  
  MethodExpression al = (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("actionListener");
  al.invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] {});
}
```

If I use my CC with a value-expression for *selection* (e.g. `selection="#{testBean.user}"`, `veSelection` is `null` (and *selection* is not printed in the debug-iteration) and I get a NPE. If I pass a String (e.g. `selection="test"`, the attribute *selection* is available in the debug-iteration, but (of course) I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.el.ValueExpression
```

How can I provide a *actionListener* and a *selection* attribute to my component, and set the selected value in the first step and then invoke the *actionListener*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the debug-iteration, you won't see value expressions in keyset nor entryset of `UIComponent#getAttributes()`. This is also explicitly mentioned in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29). In other words, that map contains only entries having static values. Only if you explicitly call `get()` on the map, and the underlying attribute is a value expression, then it will actually invoke it and return the evaluated value.

In order to get a value expression, use [`UIComponent#getValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
ValueExpression selection = getValueExpression("selection");
```

As to the method expression, well, that's the easiest if your composite extends from `UICommand`, but this is in your particular case plain clumsy. Just set the target of the listener method to the command link and use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to set the desired property in the bean. This way the backing component is unnecessary.

```html
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="actionListener" required="true" targets="link"
          method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
  <composite:attribute name="selection"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  ...
  <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{cc.attrs.data}">
    <p:commandLink id="link">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{cc.attrs.selection}" value="#{item}" />
    </p:commandLink>
  </ui:repeat>
  ...
</composite:implementation>
```